# Is it possible to Impl Iterator for a tuple struct holding a vector?

Tags: rust

If I create a struct that holds a `Vec<i32>`, I can implement the `Iterator` trait on it:

```
struct MyVec2 {
    counter: usize,
    my_vec: Vec<i32>,
}

impl MyVec2 {
    fn new(my_vec: Vec<i32>) -> Self {
        Self { counter: 0, my_vec }
    }
}

impl Iterator for MyVec2 {
    type Item = i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let i = self.my_vec.get(self.counter)?;
        self.counter += 1;
        Some(*i)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mv2 = MyVec2::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    for i in mv2 {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to implement `Iterator` for a tuple struct of this form?

```
struct MyVec(Vec<i32>);
```

So that I can call it like so?

```
pub fn main() {
    let mv = MyVec(vec![1, 2, 3]);

    for i in mv {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

All of the solutions I've tried have either produced compiler errors I can't seem to get around or have ended up in an infinite loop (e.g. when calling `.next()` on the vector inside the outer `.next` method).

Is this solvable?

Comment: This is not a problem with tuple struct, but about the fact that your original struct contains a counter, but the tuple struct doesn't. What's stopping you to do `struct MyVec(Vec<i32>, usize)` and then use `self.1` for the counter? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Restating the previous comment: *yes, it's possible*, if you do the same thing in the tuple struct you are doing in the named struct.

Comment: I see, I see. So my question was actually whether it's possible to do it without the counter? I sort of ended up doing the named struct after I gave up on the tuple struct. Is having a counter a must? No idiomatic way to do it otherwise?

Comment: Another option is to do what `Vec` itself does: not make the `MyVec` iterable, but provide an `iter()` method that _returns_ an iterator over the contents of the inner `Vec`. The counter (or reference) is then on the iterator you return, and the data structure is not burdened with it. Decoupling iteration from the data structure allows other useful things as well, e.g. multiple iterations in happening in parallel.

Comment: Why are you trying to implement `Iterator`? The trait used by `for` loops is `IntoIterator`.

Comment: You can implement `Iterator` in an extremely slow manner by popping the first element every time `next` is called, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Note that you are essentially reimplementing `vec.into_iter()`, which is implemented as a `Vec` plus a pointer to the current element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions in the comments above I went ahead and implemented a wrapper struct that sits around original tuple struct, and holds a counter.

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let mv = MyVec(vec![1, 2, 3]);

    for i in mv.iter() {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

struct MyVec<T>(Vec<T>);

// ---------------- wrapper

struct MyVecIterator<'a, T> {
    counter: usize,
    my_vec: &'a MyVec<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for MyVecIterator<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let i = self.my_vec.0.get(self.counter)?;
        self.counter += 1;
        Some(i)
    }
}

trait Iter<T> {
    fn iter(&self) -> MyVecIterator<T>;
}

impl<T> Iter<T> for MyVec<T> {
    fn iter(&self) -> MyVecIterator<T> {
        MyVecIterator {
            counter: 0,
            my_vec: self
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the answer to my original question is it's solvable, but you still need a counter somewhere. Hope helps anyone googling this in the future. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Note this iterator [effectively already exists in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) and is what you get if you [call `.into_iter()` on a `&Vec<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-1)